# Different sets but the same infimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

We have the following sets $$A_x=B_R(x)\setminus \overline{B}_r(x), ~~A_0=B_R(0)\setminus \overline{B}_r(0)$$ and the numbers: $$\beta(u)=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} x|\nabla u|^p dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^p dx}$$
The functional $$J_{x}=\frac1p\int_{A_x}(|\nabla u|^p+|u|^p) dx-\int_{A_x} F(u) dx$$
and the set $$\mathcal{M}_x=\{u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N); J'_x(u)u=0\}$$

How to prove that $$\displaystyle\inf_{\beta(u)=z,\\u\in\mathcal{M}_z} J_z(u)=\inf_{\beta(u)=0,\\u\in\mathcal{M}_0}J_0(u),\forall z\in \mathbb{R}^N$$

The Hint is to consider the change of variable $T(x)=x-z$.

Comment: I guess you should use that this change is a bijection and then the infimums are equal. By the way, what is $J'(u)u$ is it the derivative of $J$ at the point $u$, evaluated again at the point $u$ ?

Comment: Did you try to follow the hint?

Comment: @Svetoslav yes J'(u)u is the derivative of J at u evaluated at u . but i don't understand the Hint can you explain me more please

Comment: @gerw i don't understand the hint that's way i posted a question

Comment: Maybe you should replace the $u$ on the left-hand side by $u \pm z$?

Comment: where @gerw ? please]

Comment: You write it as $\inf_{\beta(\tilde u) = z, \tilde u \in \mathcal M_x}J_z(\tilde u) = \ldots$ and try $\tilde u = u + z$ or $\tilde u = u - z$.

Comment: What i must see @gerw when i set it like this?

Comment: Then you can do a change of variables in all the integrals.